# how to define a parent class, yet define a child one inside (MVC modelling)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-relationship

I am modelling a Category Model, and It should have a Lot of SubCategories (a recursive relationship)
I have applied the basics of Code First relationship Modelling:

**Category.cs**

```
public class Category
{
    [Required]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Cat_Name { get; set; }

    //Defining SubCategories
    //All subCategories have the same Class of Category
    public virtual ICollection<Category> SubCategories { get; set; } //one Category Can have a    LOT of Different SubCategories

    //Navigation Property of SubCategory, which is a Class of Category too.
   // public virtual Category Category { get; set; }          // I feel fishy about it
}
```

Now, the view is Funny, it only Sees the Category; and here is where I know My code won't just work by it's own.

*Note:* I know it's taboo to use recursive relationship, in the first place, but the end justifies the means.

Comment: Who told you it was _taboo_?

Comment: An Engineer at my college, actually.
he said: "It's very Weak Representation...avoid using it ".

Comment: I tried Code First, as you can see above, defined a Collection (as usual) to take up as many subcategories as needed, but the navigation property has been an eye opener hinting explicitly that
"Something is really Wrong"

Comment: How else would you create a hierarchical data structure. Your `Category` requires a `ParentID` property to establish the relationship between a child and its parent (the top level (root) Categories Parent would be `null`). And why _is the view funny_? If its working, add the code.

Comment: I'm reaching somewhere now...
Do I have to add another model called SubCategoy?
 (I don't want that, and I'm avoiding it, because I have product model to be added; I don't want things messed up).
an example would really help, Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps [this article](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/255/entity-framework-6-recipe-hierarchical-data-management) will help. Plenty of other examples if you google _ef hierarchical data_

Comment: `it's taboo to use recursive relationship` No it isn't. What you have is fine.

Comment: @StephenMuecke 
 That's exactly what I was searching for.
Thank you so much for helping me out!